# Pitvot stop When scroll continous

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use pivot having 3 pivotitem, and each pivot call some services. When I scroll pivot continous so so my screen is frozen  , I don't know why. Who one help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Pivot` item is loaded when it comes to screen. If you have very complex `UI`, it will take some time to create visual tree of all elements to render it on screen.

You can profile your application with standard profiling tool that comes with SDK 7.1 to find this bottle neck